# Necesito crear una Cola con tamMax, que ejecute Enqueue,Dequeue y Peek y me genera errores

Tags: c#

me recomendaron esta pagina por problemas en programación y como no encontré nada, antes de volverme loco y renunciar decidí probar surte
El problema es que mi profesor nos pide que implementemos por consola una clase "cola" (con tamaño máximo establecido) que permita ejecutar :Enqueue, Dequeue ,Peek, Vacia y llena.
Ademas un mecanismo de búsqueda que devuelva el primer elemento con el parámetro apellido. Todo utilizando nodos enlazados...
Yo Hice ésto...no me genera errores, pero al momento de compilar y ejecutar para ir viendo si va resultando me da 11 errores de compilación y me dice que los nodos no se usan...no me doy cuenta que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien pudiese ayudarme lo agradecería.

> Programa

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                
                Alumno Alumno1 = new Alumno();
                Alumno1.Nombre = "Leandro";
                Alumno1.Apellido = "Ruiz";
                Alumno1.FechaNac = new DateTime(1981/09/22);

                Alumno Alumno2 = new Alumno();
                Alumno2.Nombre = "Anahi";
                Alumno2.Apellido = "Sarda";
                Alumno2.FechaNac = new DateTime(1996/08/10);

                Alumno Alumno3 = new Alumno();
                Alumno3.Nombre = "Nicolas";
                Alumno3.Apellido = "Ruiz";
                Alumno3.FechaNac = new DateTime(2004/07/05);

                Alumno Alumno4 = new Alumno();
                Alumno4.Nombre = "Ignacio";
                Alumno4.Apellido = "Ruiz";
                Alumno4.FechaNac = new DateTime(2009/09/19);


                Cola miCola = new Cola();
                miCola.Enqueue(Alumno1);
                miCola.Enqueue(Alumno2);
                miCola.Enqueue(Alumno3);
                miCola.Enqueue(Alumno4);

                for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    Alumno1 = miCola.Dequeue(Alumno1);
                    Console.WriteLine(Alumno1);
                }

                
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora Nodo

```
    class Nodo
    {
        public Alumno Alumno { get; set; }

        public Nodo SiguienteElemento { get; set; }

        public Nodo(Alumno alumno)
        {
            this.Alumno = alumno;
            this.SiguienteElemento = null;
        }
        public Nodo(Nodo SiguienteElemento)
        {
            this.SiguienteElemento = SiguienteElemento;
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Alumno

```
public class Alumno
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaNac { get; set; }
      


    }
```

Y clase Cola

```
namespace Parcial
{
    public class Cola

    {
        private Nodo Nodo1;

            public int TamañoMaximo { get; set; }

            public int TamañoActual { get; set; }

            public Cola()
            {
            TamañoActual = 0;
            TamañoMaximo = 4;
            }
        public Cola(Alumno alumno)
        {
            Nodo nodo = new Nodo(alumno);
            Nodo1 = nodo;
        }


        public void Enqueue(Alumno alumno)
            {
            Nodo nodo = new Nodo(alumno);
            Nodo nodoActual = Nodo1;

            while (nodoActual.SiguienteElemento != null)
            {
                nodoActual = nodoActual.SiguienteElemento;
            }

            nodoActual.SiguienteElemento = nodo;

            TamañoActual++;
                
            }

            public Alumno Dequeue(Alumno alumno)
            {
                TamañoActual--;
            Nodo nodoActual = Nodo1;
            Nodo nodoAnterior = Nodo1;

            while (nodoActual.SiguienteElemento != null)
            {
                nodoAnterior = nodoActual;
                nodoActual = nodoActual.SiguienteElemento;
            }

            nodoAnterior.SiguienteElemento = null;
            return null;
        }

        public Alumno Peek(Alumno alumno)
            {
                
                return null; 
            }

            public bool Vacia()
            {
            if (Nodo1 == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
            
            }

            public bool Llena()
            {
                return (TamañoMaximo > 0 && TamañoMaximo == TamañoActual);
            }

        public Alumno Buscar(string Apellido)
        {

            Nodo nodoActual = Nodo1;

            while (nodoActual.SiguienteElemento != null)
            {
                if (nodoActual.Alumno.Apellido == Apellido)
                    return nodoActual.Alumno;

                nodoActual = nodoActual.SiguienteElemento;
            }
            return null;

        }



    }

}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Y si tengo muchos errores tontos sepan disculpar, recién empiezo

Saludos

> probé las 2 correcciones que me comentas y ambas dan error.

En el Main me pone

Error CS7036 No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido 'alumno' de 'Cola.Dequeue(Alumno)'

Y en la cola

Error CS0029 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'Parcial.Nodo' en 'Parcial.Alumno'

Estoy cada vez más perdido :(

Comment: Podes colocar el texto del compilador y en que linea te lo arroja? Tenes Queue y Stack para trabajar con ese tipo de listado generico.

Comment: Hola Ramiro, el primer erro que me tira y donde se frena todo es en la línea 33 de la Cola
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

nodoActual fue null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el fallo pueda estar en la función Dequeue que siempre retorna un valor null.

```
public Alumno Dequeue(Alumno alumno)
{
     TamañoActual--;
     Nodo nodoActual = Nodo1;
     Nodo nodoAnterior = Nodo1;

     while (nodoActual.SiguienteElemento != null)
     {
            nodoAnterior = nodoActual;
            nodoActual = nodoActual.SiguienteElemento;
     }

      nodoAnterior.SiguienteElemento = null;

      // *********  Siempre DEVUELVE NULL  ***********
      return null;
}
```

Por lo que en tu zona del código:

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     Alumno1 = miCola.Dequeue(Alumno1);
     Console.WriteLine(Alumno1);  // Aquí Alumno1 siempre es NULL
}
```

Lo que estás haciendo es pasar un parámetro Alumno1 en la función Dequeue que no usas y retornas null desde dicha función. Yo creo que tendría que quedar así corregido:

```
public Alumno Dequeue()
{
     TamañoActual--;
     Nodo nodoActual = Nodo1;
     Nodo nodoAnterior = Nodo1;

     while (nodoActual.SiguienteElemento != null)
     {
            nodoAnterior = nodoActual;
            nodoActual = nodoActual.SiguienteElemento;
     }

      nodoAnterior.SiguienteElemento = null;

      // Devolvemos el último nodo que es el que quitamos de la cola.
      return nodoActual;
}
```

En el Main{} modificamos el bucle y llamamos a Dequeue ya sin parámetros:

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     Alumno1 = miCola.Dequeue();
     Console.WriteLine(Alumno1); 
}
```